# Selenium (Java) - How to click on a link and then test if window is open?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I've worked one a project, in which I display a list of names and their corresponding hyperlinks, each hyperlink text is different, so it would look something like this,

name 1   (http://somesite.com/name1)

name 2   (http://somesite.com/name2)

name 3   (http://somesite.com/name3)

name 4   (http://somesite.com/name4)

Using the following line of code, I am able to get the required element,

```
arg1 = "http://somesite.com/name3"
WebElement urlElement = driver.findElement("//a[contains(text(), '" + arg1 + "')]");
```

With this, I do get the urlElement. Now when I click on the urlElement,

```
urlElement.click();
```

I was expecting it to open window, so that later down the link, I can call,

```
driver.switchTo().window("opened window title")
```

I was expecting this to work but for some reason it fails stating these is no window by that title.

Comment: The window title is case-sensitive.  I would recommend going through that spot, getting all of the window handles, then iterating through all of them, printing out their titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urlElement.click();   
Set<String> winids = driver.getWindowHandles();  
System.out.println("Total number of windows/tabs are:" +winids.size());  
String mainWindow = winids.iterator().next();  
String childWindow = winids.iterator().next();  
System.out.println(mainWindow);   
System.out.println(childWindow);        
driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
```

I hope this may work for you ..

it is just switching the between the window. it u want to test get the title of the window and compare with the expected window title

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info Dilip, I'll definitely give it a go and updated here. Also, nice name ... reminds me of one of my favourite Bollywood Hero of the same name :) ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Use `driver.getWindowHandles()`to get the list of handles and save them in a
```

list , check for the current handle using `driver.getWindowHandle()` and then navigate to the new handle using `driver.switchTo().window("other window")` . 
You may use `driver.close()` before switching if you wish to close out the older window.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use a same method for multiple instances of switching windows , with a bool condition. This is C# code but should be readable to anyone with Java knowledge.

> switches the focus of the object's driver to the first available
>   window not   equal to the current window   @param closeOldWindow -
>   closes previous window if true

```
protected  void switchWindows( bool closeOldWindow)
{

     String currentWindow = Driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

    // switch to first window that is not equal to the current window
    IReadOnlyCollection<String> handles =Driver.WindowHandles;
    String newWindow = handles.FirstOrDefault(handle => currentWindow != handle);

    // if there's another window found...
    if (newWindow != null) {
        if (closeOldWindow) {
            // close the current window
            Driver.Close();
        }
        // ...switch to the new window
        Driver.SwitchTo().Window(newWindow);
    }
}
```